# Installed memory: 8.00 GB (6.00 GB usable) - 2.00 GB is Hardware Reserved

Tags: windows-10, memory, bios, memory-management

I have a 64-bit Windows 10 desktop with 4GB (2x2GB) of memory that I built about nine years ago. A week ago I purchased more memory (2x2GB) of the same brand/model/specs to bring the total up to 8GB but when I installed it, windows says 8GB is installed but only 4GB is usable.

Furthermore, BIOS only recognized the 4GB. I removed the two new ones memory sticks that I purchased and went back to 4GB I originally had and it Windows now says 4GB installed and only 2GB usable. The BIOS also now recognizes only 2GB. I tried reseating the DIMMS with several combinations and it now says 8GB installed with 6GB usable (again, BIOS only recognizes 6GB). I have a dedicated GPU. Resource Monitor shows 2GB is "hardware reserved".

Heres what I've tried so far:

1. msconfig memory limits is unchecked.
2. a fresh install of Windows
3. reflashed BIOS (I was already on the latest version)
4. Ran "Speccy" software and it reads all four DIMMS
5. Checked for any RAM management settings in BIOS but there are none. Motherboard [manual URL hear](http://download1.gigabyte.us/Files/Manual/motherboard_manual_ga-ex58-ud3r_e.pdf).
6. All DIMMS have been tested individually and work fine.
7. Ran Memtest86 for 23 hours and it produced zero errors.
8. Tried both fail-safe and opimized default settings in BIOS.

There are other things I tried that I can't think of off the top of my head. Any thoughts/input would be great.

Components:

- https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128375
- https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231190&Tpk=F3-10666CL9D-4GBNQ

Specs:

- **Operating System**: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- **CPU**: Intel Core i7 920 @ 2.67GHz 65 °C. Bloomfield 45nm Technology
- **RAM**: 8.00GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 532MHz (8-8-8-20)
- **Motherboard**: Gigabyte Technology Co. Ltd. EX58-UD3R (Socket 1366) 35 °C
- **Graphics**: SyncMaster (1920x1200@59Hz). 512MB NVIDIA GeForce 9500 GT (EVGA) 60 °C
- **Storage**: 111GB Crucial_CT120M500SSD1 (SSD).
  298GB Western Digital WDC WD3200AAKS-00L9A0 (SATA) 33 °C
- **Optical Drives**:
  HL-DT-ST CDRW/DVD GCC4482 ATA Device
- **Audio**: Realtek High Definition Audio

Comment: Did you check the manual? https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-EX58-UD3R-rev-17#support-manual

Comment: Yes, I checked the manual.  I have it linked in my original post.  There is nothing in the manual about memory management that would affect this issue.  I have the rev. 1.0, btw.

Comment: any chance that your monitor is plugged into the onboard video and not your GPU?

Comment: Its plugged into the GPU.  I don't think the MB has a built-in video slot as I don't see one.